# Comparing an array of strings with an array of objects and removing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a React app and have a `this.state.filesAccepted` which is an array of objects. It looks like this:

[image: filesAccepeted]

I also have an array of strings called `filenames` that looks like the following:

[image: filenames]

I'd like to compare the two and if there is a match, the object should be removed from the array in `this.state.filesAccepted`. For example, if a string in `filenames` (`"eicartest1"`) matches the `key` in `filesAccepted` (`key: "eicartest1"`), it should remove that object from the array.

There may be a more efficient and cleaner way of doing this, but for the comparison, I think I need to do two loops like the following:

```
_.map(filenames, f => {
    _.map(this.state.filesAccepted, fa => {
        if (f === fa.key) {
            delete entire object from array;
        }
    });
});
```

How should I be handling the delete? Is there a more efficient way to make this comparison besides `map` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
this.state.filesAccepted.filter(
  file=>!filenames.includes(file.key)
)
```

That results in an array that only has items where the src is not in filenames

To create a new state with the new filesAccepted you can do:

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  filesAccepted:this.state.filesAccepted.filter(
    file=>!filenames.includes(file.key)
  )
})
```

Comment: Array.prototype.includes() is not supported in all browsers, It failed in IE10 or IE11 for me once and I replaced all occurrences to `_.includes()`

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz This is a react app so I guess there is webpack building it so that is a matter of creating the right build profile for outdated browsers.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz if browser support is a concern, use `indexOf`.

Comment: @HMR I am also using webback, it is a `create-react-app` but somehow it failed

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I think you need to add [polyfil](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) for older browser support and use lower ES version. For modern browsers you don't need to have babel change anything

Comment: If browser support is a concern, you should use *polyfills* rather than limiting yourself to writing in obsolete versions of the language, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to remove unmatched items

```js
const filesAccepted = this.state.filesAccepted.filter(obj => !_.includes(filenames, obj.key));

this.setState({filesAccepted});
```

Comment: @HMR I explained it in comments below your answer :) It's not supported by all browsers